# For fetching a students applied programs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mern

I am trying to fetch all the programs for the current applicant who is logged in and has applied for their bachelor's degree and store the fetched programs object id in an array.

I have tried the following but I'm not sure if it will work at first. Secondly, it will be quite helpful if you let me know what should I do to make it possible. I have shared the code I wrote. It is a MERN stack project and the backend is purely javascript.

Let me know if you can help me with the code below:

```
// @route  GET /api/programs/applied-programs
// @desc   Get all applied programs
// @access Private
router.get('/applied-programs', auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const applicant = await Applicant.findOne({ user: req.user.id })
      .select('-password')
      .populate('user', ['email']);

    let res = [];
    const appliedPrograms = applicant.appliedPrograms.forEach(program => {
      if (program) {
        res = [program.id];
      }
      return res;
    });

    res.json(appliedPrograms);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
    return res.status(500).send('Server Error');
  }
});
```

Comment: What happens when you run the program?

Comment: It does not give the resultant response. Infact it returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

So I just solved it myself. Just remembered that .forEach() function you have to pass an object the condition I was using was putting a check on the programs and I was passing the ids inside the array itself. Which surely is the wrong way to do it. So for now by using the .map() and mapping through the list of object and fetching their ids I just got what I wanted.

This is the proper way of doing so.

```
// @route  GET /api/programs/applied-programs
// @desc   Get all applied programs
// @access Private
router.get('/applied-programs/:id', auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const applicant = await Applicant.findOne({ user: req.user.id })
      .select('-password')
      .populate('user', ['email']);

    let response = [];
    const appliedPrograms = applicant.appliedPrograms.map(
      program => program.id
      // if (program) {
      //   response = [program.id];
      // }
      // return response;
      // }
    );

    response = appliedPrograms;

    res.json(response);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
    return res.status(500).send('Server Error');
  }
});
```